# Migrate Drupal site from XAMPP to MAMP

Tags: drupal, xampp, mamp, migrate

I created a Drupal website in a XAMPP environment, but would like to further develop it in a MAMP environment. That is, without losing all the content I already added. I changed the settings.php file like this

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost:8889',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

But I get the error:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8889' (2) in lock_may_be_available() (line 164 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kooknet2/includes/lock.inc).

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tiny error, you've got the port as part of your host string (`:8889`) when you should be adding it to the array key that actually says `port`. Try this:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => array (
      'database' => 'drupal',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '8889',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This will fix the PDO error, but it likely won't solve the root issue of moving between xampp and mamp. They each use different mysql instances so you won't be able to connect to your xampp mysql db from mamp (unless you were running them both at the same time and different ports, but that kind of defeats the purpose)

Answer (score 0):

If you have local MySQL server, login to it from console, check user-pass-port. It see,s you haven't MySQL instance on 8899 port

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [backup and migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to grab a copy of your database. Then setup your site on mamp (with a new db/install), and use BAM to restore from your backup.

If you're using the same file path, there shouldn't be any other steps to worry about otherwise you might need to copy/move your files directory and also reconfigure your file path settings in the drupal interface. (Also you may need to be aware that any links to internal content that is embedded in your node body may also need to be adjusted so the path is correct)